# Pyspark extracting exactly 4 consecutive numeric digit from a column and return it in a new column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am very new in using pyshark and have no idea how to do it

I am trying to extract from a title column.

Some value in the title column are:

Under Ground2(1990)
Waterword(1995)
Incredible
Skate (1991) board
That girl 2002”
I am trying to get:

1990
1995
1991
2002

This is what i have tried :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
from pyspark.sql.functions import      regexp_replace

movies_DF=movies_DF.withColumn('title',   regexp_replace(movies_DF.title, "\(",""))
movies_DF=movies_DF.withColumn('title', regexp_replace(movies_DF.title, "\)",""))
movies_DF=movies_DF.withColumn('yearOfRelease',(f.expr('substring(title,-4)')))
```

My output column that have:

1990

1995

board

2002”

dible

Comment: Can you share the code that you've got so far? I suspect `withColumn` and regex should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html) function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, col

df = df.withColumn('Year', regexp_extract(col('Title'), r'\((\d{4})\)$', 1))
df.show()
```

---

```
+-------------------+----+
|              Title|Year|
+-------------------+----+
|Under Ground2(1990)|1990|
|    Waterword(1995)|1995|
+-------------------+----+
```